# Is this sentence correct? "Username have to consists only of ..."

Tags: grammar

Is it correct to say?

> Username have to consists only of letters, numbers and low dash.

Answer (score 5):

Following the basic rules of grammar as indicated in the site *Grammarbook*, it would be more correct to say:

```
"Usernames have to consist only of letters, numbers, and low dash."
```

If you are pertaining to the plural version of "username"

or

```
"A username has to consist only of letters, numbers, and low dash."
```

If you are pertaining to the singular version of "username".

For more information, you can visit: http://www.grammarbook.com/grammar/subjectVerbAgree.asp

Comment: By the way, that "low dash" probably translates to "underscore" in America.